# Cloud Shell: Editor is not loading in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

So I have been following the following step for past few months:

1. Log in to Google Cloud Console from Chrome's incognito mode
2. Activate Cloud Shell
3. From there, I usually opened Editor and managed my files in a new window

Today while I was following the above steps, this issue raised up:
[image]

Basically, I cannot open editor anymore. I have already went through similar posts, and my issue is that I am using incognito where browser extensions or cookies shouldn't be an issue.

I am facing this problem for the first time and if anyone knows what is the cause or any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
For now Microsoft Edge InPrivate Mode is working for me. I am still interested in fixing the issue for Chrome.

Have reported the issue in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168728384). Please "start" for more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This started happening recently because third-party cookies stopped being supported in Incognito mode [as of Chrome 83](https://venturebeat.com/2020/05/19/google-chrome-83/).  Third-party cookies are required for the editor to work because of the way the open-source [Theia IDE](https://theia-ide.org/) is integrated into Cloud Shell.  The team is exploring various fixes, but in the mean time the following workaround should work:

1. In Incognito Mode, click on the crossed out 'eye' icon on the address bar.
2. Click on 'Site not working?'
3. Click on 'Allow cookies'

Safari problem stems from the same issue, but I am not certain if a similar workaround exists.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue myself (I tried this on Chrome running on both ChromeOS and MacOS) - it looks like a bug so in this case I'd recommend reporting it on [Google's Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) (you can even put a link to this post).

UNfortunately it looks like it's not just the Chrome browser. I tried this on Safari 13.1 and found the issue you described is also present.

I didn't check other browsers but IssueTracker is the way to go. And be patient :)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will create an issue and hope someone will have a look into it. Do you have any suggestions on how I can proceed until they fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with your findings - if you think my answer helped you in any way I'd aprreciate if you accepted and/or upvoted it :)